# Should an AngularJS + nginx codebase be dockerized

Tags: angularjs, node.js, docker, npm, gulp

I have a AngularJS front-end project that runs on nginx and communicates to a back-end java server (separate from this codebase). I find myself running the following commands to install the package:

```
# make sure node, npm, and gulp are installed
npm install
gulp watch
```

Should the above be dockerized or is it preferred to run these projects via the commands. The code will be modified locally as we develop (so we'd probably need to configure a volume that maps to the project's directory).

What would be the advantages or disadvantages of dockerizing the above vs. just running the above commands to get the project started? The main goal here is to reduce the time it takes for a new developer to get started/comfortable with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well the only benefit I can think of right now of why you might want to dockerize this application is if you would prefer someone else to be able to deploy the application a little easier (with the only dependency being Docker and access to a repository where any built containers are being stored). i.e. they could simply issue a docker run command and reference the application / build tag, and they'd have a running containerized application.

The other possible benefit I can foresee is portability across systems that are target environments. The only dependency again is Docker.

Then you have the added benefits that come with support for automatic container builds, built in versioning to name a few.

Also note, you could set up a remote SCM to store code / Dockerfiles to automate build / deploys, if you would like to move away from local host development.

If your main goal is to is to reduce the time it takes for a new developer to get started/comfortable with the project, then the the biggest issue you will face is OS (Windows/Linux use). An alternative solution to Docker would be to use Vagrant.